# Using if with differents possibilites

Tags: java

I need to use a conditional if but i need evaluates differents possibilites. For example:

```
if (a==1 OR a==2 OR a=10)
 {
   do something
 }
```

But i don't know how to do it. Any suggestions?

Comment: -1, you could have found this out in a matter of seconds by just doing a search

Comment: I do not understand why there is a +1?

Comment: I am also quite astonished as to how this question has provoked so many plain **wrong** answers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of your "OR" use ||:

```
if (a==1 || a==2 || a==10)
  {
     do something
  }
```

Comment: No problem, but next time you should search a bit more before asking such a question here.

Answer (score 1):

You can collect your *differents possibilites* in a list. Then just use this snippet:

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
list.add(x); list.add(y); ....
if(list.contains(a))
   do something;
```